# PyCharm ругается на open(path, mode): warning - unexpected argument

Tags: python, pycharm

Пишу скрипт на питоне 2.4.3 (такое старье нужно, так как скрипт должен работать в чистой МСВС). В качестве IDE используется PyСharm 4.5.1.

Проблема в том, что Pycharm  по непонятной причине подсвечивает строку типа:

```
f=open('/path/file', 'rb')
```

как *warning - unexpected argument.*

Почему так и что с этим делать?

Comment: Что покажет PyCharm, если перейти к объявлению `open`? Может быть ее параметры как-то хитро были определены. На крайний случай, есть `Disable once with comment` - поможет?

Comment: переходит к файлу .pycharm40/system/python_stubs/-1149422919/__builtin__.py там идет в class open ( object)

Comment: Можете вылить этот класс куда-нибудь на [pastebin](pastebin.com)? Меня интересуют описанные в нем функции

Comment: Выложить проблема.  На работе инета нет и флэшки  цеплять нельзя (сижу с теле- оборонка. но там все функции класса вида: def __init__(self): pass # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__

Comment: Если у функции `__init__` только параметр `self`, то это объясняет, почему ругается PyCharm. Объяснить, почему она не принимает других аргументов, сейчас не могу, не застал уже Python 2.4. Если только на выходных получится поковыряться. Попробуйте воспользоваться "Disable once with comment" - хоть глаза мозолить не будет.

Comment: Я  так понял он потерял стандартные функции file и пытается восстановить их по документации. Как это исправить не понятно.

Comment: Он не потерял их. То что Вы видите - результат декомпиляции. Файлы с исходным кодом Вы вряд ли найдете на своей машине. PyCharm ориентируется на метод `__init__`. Поскольку он не принимает аргументов (за исключением `self`), PyCharm ругается, когда вы создаете объект, передавая два параметра. Если данный код работает (а он должен, судя по документации), то беспокоиться не о чем.

Comment: `open` является другим именем для `file` на Питоне 2.4. `file` принимает несколько аргументов, что подтвреждается как [документацией](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/built-in-funcs.html) так и [исходным кодом](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/037cdc57d965f7e19169a83cd5daf8c20bea7cc0/Objects/fileobject.c#L1840). PyCharm тут не прав.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что со времен PyCharm 4.5.1 уже прошло много релизов PyCharm. В 2017.1.2 (CE) проблема не воспроизводится. Скорее всего вопрос уже не актуален.

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то будет писаться так:
 `f=open(r'/path/file', 'rb')`.

Comment: Прямые слэши не нужно экранировать, только обратные. Скорее всего это был баг в линтере PyCharm'а, и скорее всего проблема уже не актуальна.